# Properness of a map defined by partition of unity

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and let $F:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous proper map.
Also let $\{ U_i \}$ be a countable cover of $M$ with each $U_i$ having $x_i$ as representative and let $\{ \varphi_i \}$ be a partition of the unity subordinated to $\{ U_i \}$.
I want to show that
$$ \tilde{F}(y) = \sum_{i} \varphi_i(y) F(x_i) $$
is a proper map.

So to show properness I tried to use the fact that it maps unbounded sequence to unbounded sequence but I don't see what to do.

Comment: If all $x_i$ are equal to say $x_0$ (and so $x_0$ belongs to all $U_i$ which is possible) then your function is constant $F(x_0)$, and thus not proper (unless $M$ is compact). Or did you miss some additional assumptions?

Comment: @freakish I think we may admit that all $x_i$ are different yes

Comment: I don't think this is enough. The image of $\tilde{F}$ is a subset of convex hull of $\{F(x_i)\}$ and so if the last set is bounded, then the convex hull is (relatively) compact. And thus it's preimage is whole $M$, right? Maybe $\{F(x_i)\}$ should be assumed to be unbounded?

Comment: What do you mean by having $x_i$ as a representative? Do you mean $x_i \in U_i$?

Comment: I think, you forgot to assume that the cover $\{U_i\}$ is locally finite and that each subset $U_i$ is relatively compact in $M$. Without the first assumption, there is no partition of unity. Without the second assumption, properness will surely fail.